# Azure Function with Blob Trigger - Stage Slot Still Firing on Old Container

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure Function fired by a blob trigger.  The function is deployed using a deployment slot (zero downtime), with auto-swap on the stage slot enabled to the production slot.  My latest deployment changed the blob container used for the trigger.  The deployment was successful and the new function in the production slot is trigger from any new blob in the new container.

The issue:
Even though the stage slot is specified with 0% traffic it is still being fired by any new blob that appears in the old container still, why?

Comment: I guess, irrespective of the slots, Azure Functions triggers if any new blob uploaded to its container!

Comment: @HariKrishna so I guess my understanding of the 0% traffic setting is not correct.  I presumed that even for a blob triggered function 0% traffic would mean any new blobs would not fire the function deployed to the stage slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my observation,
Irrespective of the Traffic Percentage, Azure Functions will trigger when the new blob is uploaded to the container.

I have deployed a Blob Trigger Function App to the Azure Functions (.NET 6 Stack - Premium Hosting Plan) with Auto Swap Enabled from the stage slot to prod slot.

- Stage Slot - old container - Eg, samples-workitems
- Prod Slot - Function with same code but new container - Eg:  prodcontainer

I tested by uploading the files to both the blob containers one by one and checked the invocation logs. Even though traffic is 0%, both slot functions are fired when containers are getting updated with new blobs.

Stage slot - old container - `samples-workitems`

[image]

prod slot - new container - `prodcontainer`
[image]

> Traffic in the deployment slots means Incoming requests will be redirected to the respective target slot during auto-swap without down time.

For more information, you can refer [Azure Functions Deployment Slots - MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots).

Comment: Thanks Hari, yes this is exactly the scenario that I am experiencing.  So, my conclusion to this is that to stop the stage slot from firing it will have to be disabled, since it is being invoke for no reason.

Comment: If this is by design then I have an issue where I now have a stage slot and production slot both possibly being triggered and processing the same data.

Comment: I would recommend raising the issue by mentioning your Kudu Streaming logs screenshots in the GitHub of Azure Functions Dep-Slots Repo link in the given answer > scroll down to the bottom > Click on "This page" that opens GitHub Repro Issue Open Page and add the complete issue details.